# Unserialize DateInterval object

Tags: php, serialization

I want to store a custom object, containing a DateInterval attribute in a file, using the `symfony cache` of my project. This one uses the `serialize()` function. But, when the object is retrieved (with `unserialize()` then), the returned object does not match the one I had saved before.

I tried to reproduce the operation without going through the cache, and the problem would come from the `unserialize` function.

```php
$iOne = new \DateInterval('P1D');
$cachedIOne = serialize($iOne);
$returnIOne = unserialize($cachedIOne);
```

The "days" attribute when creating the object (`$iOne`) is `false` in Boolean.
After `unserialize` (`$returnIOne`), the attribute becomes an integer with `0` for value.
Is there a solution to the problem? or another way to store an object as a string (`json_encode` is not usable easily on custom objects)?

Comment: Does the difference between `false` and `0` make an actual difference to the behaviour of the object…?

Comment: Yes. The object is different depending on the value of this attribute. See the documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Answer (score 1):

After some research I've found [one php-bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70153) reported at 2015-07-27. There was a [patch right in this bug](https://bugs.php.net/patch-display.php?bug=70153&patch=dateinterval-unserialize&revision=1438007244) proposed by [Christoph M. Becker](https://github.com/cmb69).

Obviously, that this bug was forgotten (maybe because it was reported about PHP-Version=5.6.1).

Anyway, I opened [a PR in php-src github repository](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/4687) and made some extra-changes. After a while this bugfix should appear in php-7.2 bugfix-release.

**Edit 1**: My pull-request successfully merged.

To see the result it's necessary to update PHP at least to `7.2.25`.